# Sending form params as body for Guzzle POST request

Tags: post, guzzle, eventbrite

I'm a bit confused about Guzzle's deprecation of sending body parameters, and throwing an exception if $body is an array. The recommended way is seemingly to replace body parameters with form_params.
I'm posting to the eventbrite API here
https://www.eventbrite.com.au/developer/v3/quickstart/

and when doing the following:

```
$response = $this->guzzleClient->request('POST', $item->eventbriteEndpoint, ['form_params' => $item->parameters]);
```

It doesn't work (and actually responds like it's received a GET request)

After much trial and error, I discovered I need to json_encode the parameters into a json string and add them into the body like so

```
$response = $this->guzzleClient->request('POST', $item->eventbriteEndpoint, ['body' => json_encode($item->parameters));
```

So what is going on here, is form_params the correct replacement for body, and why? Is json_encoding body the correct way to do it, and if so why is form_params mentioned everywhere and this not common knowledge? Something is wrong here, is it

1. My understanding of form_params and body parameters in a guzzle POST request (most likely)
2. Guzzle doesn't handle POST requests correctly (unlikely)
3. The Eventbrite API is not receiving POST requests correctly.

I find guzzle to be incredibly opaque tbh, xdebugging down the rabbit hole usually asks more questions than it answers.

I've actually just discovered something even more bizarre on the Eventbrite end - a POST request to create a new event uses form_params, and updating an event requires the params as json in the body. What.

Comment: Did you find anything out about this? I think I am getting a similar error when trying to post on guzzle `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`